# Publish through command line c# wcf

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild

I have a wcf application which I am trying to build/publish through the command line. I am able to get the output but then the "bin" directory does not have the same folder structure.

For example:

When built/published through VS the `bin` folder looks like

```
bin
->Test
   -> Files.dll
```

But when I run the same through `command line`

```
bin
->Files.dll
```

The Test folder is missing. I tried to do a xcopy from the bin folder. But it turns out that the bin folder does not have files there.

Here is the batch file I am executing

```
SET DestPath = "EmailNotificationPublish" 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  EmailNotification.sln /property:OutDir=%DestPath% /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU";DeployOnBuild=True
```

Please let me know if any other files are required.

**UPDATE**
My .csproj looks like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{B35C5165-44AD-472F-8071-22AEA022F77B}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>D:\EmailNotificationPublish</OutputPath>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>EmailNotification.Service</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>EmailNotification.Service</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="EmailNotificationService.svc" />
    <Content Include="Templates\BasicEmailTemplate.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Templates\DueDateEmailTemplate.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Templates\CompleteEmailTemplate.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="EmailNotificationService.svc.cs">
      <DependentUpon>EmailNotificationService.svc</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="IEmailNotificationService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-03265b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>64568</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>
          </IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
          <EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>True</EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the .csproj that has "Test" in it?  Post build event?  Something.  This one is tricky, you may need to post your entire .csproj file.

Comment: @granadaCoder Updated with complete .csproj

Comment: Can you comment this out, and see if it affects anything.   "    <OutputPath>D:\EmailNotificationPublish</OutputPath>"

Comment: I already tried that, I was not able to find the location of the publish. It was not present in the bin folder.

Comment: Can you change this "OutDir=%DestPath%" to "OutXXXDirXXX=%DestPath%, just to see if that will put the results in the \bin\Debug and/or the bin\Release directories?

Comment: @granadaCoder Din't help

Comment: What about using the (non 64) msbuild.exe ?       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

Comment: It was a good suggestion, but still the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest opening up the .csproj files.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>.\bin\Debug</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>.\bin\Release</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And paying close attention to the

You may be (unknowingly) calling 2 different "conditions" (usually the $(Configuration)).
(Notice how you are explicitedly setting the "Configuration" when you call this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  EmailNotification.sln /property:OutDir=%DestPath% /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU";DeployOnBuild=True
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the OutputPath in my .csproj. I updated the question with .csproj file.